# Clean way to extract results, or aggregate errors using Result, in f#

Tags: f#

I have a system where I collect data from a grid. It is organized in rows.
Each row processed returns a `Result<data, string list>` object.
The list in the error case is a list of errors encountered during the parsing. Each row can have multiple errors, but only one valid result.

I would like to aggregate the data to a list `data list` if there are no errors, or make a complete list of errors, in the `string list` form if there is at least one error.

The final return type is `Result<data list, string list>`

I have the following code:

```
let hasErrors =
    gridRows |> List.exists (fun r -> match r with | Ok _ -> false | Error _ -> true)

// build the layer list, or return the errors
match hasErrors with
| false -> Ok (
            gridRows
            |> List.map (fun r ->
                match r with
                | Ok layer -> layer
                | Error _  -> failwith "this should never execute"
            )
          )
| true -> Error (
                gridRows
                |> List.collect (fun r ->
                    match r with
                    | Ok _ -> []
                    | Error messages -> messages
                )
             )
```

But this feels very clunky and hard to read.

Using Result<>, is there a way to do:

- if any error, collect all error elements in a list and return a result with that list
- if no errors, collect all the ok elements in a list and return a result with that list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do here is a fold, which is a way to iterate over all elements of the list while keeping some sort of state as you go. The state in this case would be the ultimate resulting value - either `Ok` with all the values or `Error` with all the errors.

The folding function would be pretty simple:

```
let f state item = 
    match state, item with
    | Ok prevResults, Ok res -> Ok (prevResults @ [res])
    | Ok _, Error errs -> Error errs
    | Error errs, Ok _ -> Error errs
    | Error prevErrs, Error errs -> Error (prevErrs @ errs)
```

This function looks at both the "result accumulated so far" (aka "state") and the current item, and for each of the four possibilities, returns the appropriate new "result accumulated so far".

And then you can just use this function to fold over the list, with the initial state being `Ok []`:

```
gridRows |> List.fold f (Ok [])
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to remind you all of the _'disjunctive pattern'_, regarding the second and third line of the match: `| _, Error errs | Error errs, _ -> ...` is so much more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) .

Comment: @kaefer my goal was to cleanly show the four possibilities while avoiding more topics that have to be explained

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Understanding the brevity, yet isn't the point of your answer that these two branches coalesce into the `Error` case? You can still put the alternatives onto separate lines...

Comment: What's this `@` syntax? Also, I don't think the two `Error` cases can be collapsed: one will have to wrap the item in a list like `Error [err]` while the other will already be a list.

Comment: `@` is F# operator for concatenating lists